# mod rewrite not reading the rule from htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am using WAMP (apache 2.2.9 and PHP 5.4.17). I have few simple mod rewrite rules that are working on production server (CentOS) but on my windows machine one rule is being ignored. I spent 3 days on finding solution but none worked.

Here is mod rewrite rules

```
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^reviews/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ page-review.php?t=$1&m=$2&s=$3 [L] #This is being ignored by Apache
RewriteRule ^reviews/?$ reviews.php [L]
RewriteRule ^reviews/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-reviews/?$ reviews.php?r=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^file/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/s([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/f([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ file.php?c=$1&s=$2&st=$3&&m=$4&t=$5 [L]
```

The first rewrite rule is being ignored by Apache. Surprisingly, when I remove all contents from htaccess it still reads my rules. I have turned on mod rewrite log and here is the log detail

```
log for http://localhost/mysite/reviews/product/11/samsung.html

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:37:34 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#1821000/subreq] (1) [perdir /mydir/] pass through /mydir/reviews.php
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:37:34 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#17cc4f0/initial] (1) [perdir /mydir/] pass through /mydir/reviews.php
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:37:34 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#17d0500/initial] (1) [perdir /mydir/] pass through /mydir/reviews.php
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:37:34 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#1835050/initial] (1) [perdir /mydir/] pass through /mydir/reviews.php
```

As you can see above, instead of rewriting above request to page-review.php it reads reviews.php file

Here is another request which works fine

```
log for http://localhost/mysite/file/downloads/software/f5983-docs.html

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:39:42 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#47f4188/initial] (2) [perdir /mydir/] rewrite 'file/downloads/software/f5983-docs.html' -> 'file.php?c=downloads&s=45&st=software&&m=5983&t=docs'
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:39:42 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#47f4188/initial] (2) [perdir /mydir/] trying to replace prefix /mydir/ with /mysite/
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:39:42 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#47f4188/initial] (1) [perdir /mydir/] internal redirect with /mysite/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2013:14:39:42 +0100] [localhost/sid#453140][rid#47ed3e0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /mydir/] pass through /mydir/file.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules mostly look alright. Try this slightly modified code:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^reviews/(\w+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ page-review.php?t=$1&m=$2&s=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/?$ reviews.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^reviews/(\w+)-reviews/?$ reviews.php?r=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^file/(\w+)/s([0-9]+)-(\w+)/f([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ file.php?c=$1&s=$2&st=$3&&m=$4&t=$5 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Btw regex in your last rule won't match `file/downloads/software/f5983-docs.html`

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced MultiViews with -MultiViews and it solved my problem. Wondering what's the scope of -MultiViews here? I have noticed you have replaced (.*) with ([^.]+) can you explain this rule and why [NC]?

Comment: NC is for ignore case comparison. In regex using negation `[^.]+` is usually safer than `.*` (which can grab everything sometimes). Also `MultiViews` should be switched off while using mod_rewrite since Apache does its own URL rewrite when `MultiViews` is turned on.